# Views 3.0 rc1 and node count for taxonomy terms

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, nodes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Views and node count for taxonomy terms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/views-and-node-count-for-taxonomy-terms)

Just watched this topic for the answer [Views and node count for taxonomy terms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/views-and-node-count-for-taxonomy-terms) - but i didn't succeed.

As far as i understand - when i use contextual filters it would show only term count not node count in terms.

Could someone explain to me how to do that with relationships?

Comment: The question you link to has a good answer with a view you can import.