# Count content types which have taxonomy term

Tags: views, nodes

I have a content type where a taxonomy term is associated to it . I would like to know how could i count the number of content types by taxonomy term ?

Comment: do you mean you want to  get count of nodes of particular content type by a specific term?

Comment: @AnoopJoseph yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following snippet, to get count of nodes by passing the term id

```
<?php
  $tids = array(1); //An array of term IDs to match.
  $nodes = taxonomy_select_nodes($tids);
  echo count($nodes) ;
?>
```

Edit:

You can use views to achieve this, check this [similar question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/views-and-node-count-for-taxonomy-terms) . It explains an example

Comment: I have a list of terms and i would like to show the number of nodes next to the term name...

Comment: i edited answer please checkout the similar question

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Term Node Count](http://drupal.org/project/term_node_count) module. Though it is still for Drupal 6, but you will find the Drupal 7 compatible version from [this discussion](http://drupal.org/node/603868#comment-4421144).