# Display number of nodes in taxonomy view filter

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a view, with an exposed filter based on a taxonomy. It works like it should.

Now, i need to display the number of nodes who are under each terms of the taxonomy, like so :

Term Test (6)

Term OtherTest (5)

Term Test3 (7)

The number have to be displayed in the dropdown list.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Views and node count for taxonomy terms](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/views-and-node-count-for-taxonomy-terms)

Comment: @Chapabu : no, the difference is that mine has to serve as filter on the view, not just displayed inline as some text