# How do I show a term's node count in grid format?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I've been looking around for instructions on how to show the node count for taxonomy terms, and, while I did find instructions on [Views and node count for taxonomy terms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/views-and-node-count-for-taxonomy-terms), it wasn't exactly what I need. The terms and their counts do show up next to each other quite nicely (Ex: Term A(13), Term B(2), Term C(17), etc.). However, they only show up as an unformatted list.

I need them in a grid form. Although I did play with the settings for quite a while, I wasn't able to get it work, and didn't find anything else on the web that fixed the problem.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you import the view proposed in [that answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/1348/11884), you will get a table with 2 columns: term name on the left, number of nodes on the right. That's a block, not a page, but that's a good start for your needs, IMHO.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8295661/1999581) to learn how to import views.