# How to create heirarchical taxonomy menu/list using VIEWS

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

How can I create a view of taxonomy terms for a content type (Story and Page) and display it to a block with parent and child relationship?

What I want is to take a "Taxonomy Term" based on "Content Types".

Example:

```
Fruits (5)
  - Apple (3)
  - Banana (2)
Vegetables (4)
  - Beans (1)
  - Eggplant (2)
  - Onions (1)
```

Demo: 
http://worldstogethertravel.com

Menu on right sidebar: (Of Cultural Interest)

This menu is created using taxonomy_menu module not VIEWS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Views Tree](https://drupal.org/project/views_tree) module..

Project page says

> Views Tree module provides a tree-based style plugin for Views. It is
>   equivalent to the tree-based style template from Views 1.
>
> It is based off of the list style. Although it generates a nested
>   view, there is still only a single query run for the view making it
>   quite performant.

For node count, you can implement same using views.. Check this post [Views and node count for taxonomy terms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/views-and-node-count-for-taxonomy-terms)..