# Views node count Taxonomy term as a field

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, nodes

There are a few other posts about this in general but none of them explain how to make this a field so i can keep my other fields such as Title and Image.

I am making a video site, and the taxonomy 'category' has an image attached to each term. Therefore i want the number of nodes tagged with a specific category to show but also have all the other fields i use.

I tried solutions found here: [Views and node count for taxonomy terms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/views-and-node-count-for-taxonomy-terms)

The above suggestions seem to ignore my image and title fields i currently have styled

hope this makes sense

Comment: try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w22Utjm-chs

Comment: Thank You! With a bit of fumbling around after watching this video i got it.   I was getting an error with my original fields, so i had to delete them and add them again. Luckily my custom text field with divs didn't need to change. Thanks for the tip!!!

Comment: Anyone out there with the same issue: Setup the Relationship first ('Taxonomy term: Content with term '). Then set 'use aggregation' to yes. Once that is done, all newly created fields should show up with no errors

Comment: in that case, You can update your question now. :)

Comment: Please do not edit "[solved]" into question's title. We are not a support service, we are a Question and Answer forum. If question is useful for future visitors, leave it be. If it's not, it shouldn't be asked here in the first place. The closest thing to "solved" we have here is **marking an answer as accepted**. It means *"I, the one who asked, confirms this answer to be good and solve my original issue"*. So if you want to mark your question, then go and mark the very answer that "solves" it :)

Answer (score 2):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w22Utjm-chs

This video explains the process.

I found my old fields didn't work anymore once i added aggregation so, you might want to remember and fields and styling you have made because you might have to rebuild the fields once aggregation is turned on.

1. add a relationship (under advanced tab) 'Taxonomy term: Content with term'.
2. turn on aggregation (advanced tab at the bottom).
3. create a field 'Taxonomy Term: Name'.
4. add any other fields associated with the taxonomy such as image or any others you created.

Style everything and done!