# How to get hits count of nodes related to a taxonamy vocabulary

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I had implemented 2 taxonomy vocabularies with some taxonomy terms in my site. There are two content type, Events & documents with a field term reference to these vocabularies. I need to display the view count of each vocabulary separately with taxonomy pages, events & file download related to particular taxonomy. Any way to implement.

Layout

[image]

Comment: Please EDIT your question to (a) explain how you created the tables in the screenprint and (b) what you have tried so far and where you got stuck (or what did not work as expected).

Comment: screenprint is the design concept. I followed [link] (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/views-and-node-count-for-taxonomy-terms). But the data is getting repeated. Cant aggregate it. In views how can we group the results?.

Comment: Please EDIT your question to move your comment to there. And indicate which of the 5 answers there you tried. And then ADD the details (+ extra screenprints?) of what you achieved so far and what the remaining issue /question is ... Just trying to help, OK?