# Show aggregated field if empty

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a view which shows all taxonomy terms in a vocabulary. Also it shows the count of the nodes which have been categorized with them. Created according to this answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/1348/51684

Example:

- Fruits(3)
- Vegetables(7)
- Drinks(14)

If one taxonomy term has no nodes referencing to it, it isn't displayed. So there is no "Cakes(0)" output.

Is there any way to do this?

My Settings:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'event_type_select';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$view->human_name = 'Veranstaltungstyp Auswahl';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['group_by'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['reset_button_label'] = 'Zurücksetzen';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['tags']['first'] = '« erste Seite';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['tags']['previous'] = '‹ vorherige Seite';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['tags']['next'] = 'nächste Seite ›';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['tags']['last'] = 'letzte Seite »';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'grid';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = '3';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: Taxonomie-Begriff: Inhalt using Typ */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_typ_node']['id'] = 'reverse_field_typ_node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_typ_node']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_typ_node']['field'] = 'reverse_field_typ_node';
/* Feld: COUNT(DISTINCT Inhalt: Nid) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_typ_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['group_type'] = 'count_distinct';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['hide_alter_empty'] = FALSE;
/* Feld: Taxonomie-Begriff: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['text'] = '<a href="/veranstaltungen/[name]">[name] ([nid])</a>';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['hide_alter_empty'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['link_to_taxonomy'] = TRUE;
/* Filter criterion: Taxonomie-Vokabular: Maschinenlesbarer Name */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['id'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_vocabulary';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['field'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['value'] = array(
  'veranstaltungstyp' => 'veranstaltungstyp',
);
/* Filter criterion: Inhalt: Datum - end date (field_date:value2) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value2']['id'] = 'field_date_value2';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value2']['table'] = 'field_data_field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value2']['field'] = 'field_date_value2';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value2']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_typ_node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value2']['operator'] = '>=';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value2']['default_date'] = 'now';
$translatables['event_type_select'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Zurücksetzen'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Items per page'),
  t('- All -'),
  t('Offset'),
  t('« erste Seite'),
  t('‹ vorherige Seite'),
  t('nächste Seite ›'),
  t('letzte Seite »'),
  t('field_typ'),
  t('<a href="/veranstaltungen/[name]">[name] ([nid])</a>'),
);
```

Edit: This worked, untill I added the Date filter. I need to count only nodes with a date in the future (or today).