# How do I show the number of nodes using a taxonomy term?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 8

Somebody asked [Views and node count for taxonomy terms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/views-and-node-count-for-taxonomy-terms). I am trying to do the same, but with Drupal 8.

I follow the steps reported in that question, and I get a count of the taxonomy term (say "fruit"), but when I click on it there is a page that lists "fruit" multiple times, instead of listing the pages themselves.

If I do not do a count. then when I click on the taxonomy term I get the correct listing page (e.g. *apple*, *orange*, *pear*).

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 13):

The following worked for me in Drupal-8.0.6.

Note that for some reason 'Content NID' is not offered as a field for the 'Content with term' relationship, so I used UUID instead and it worked.

1. Create a Taxonomy Term view (with a field `Taxonomy term: name`, usually linked to the term page)
2. Relationship > Taxonomy term: Content with term (will be called `node`).
3. Advanced: Use aggregation: Yes
4. Add Field > `Content: UUID` with relationship `node`
5. Aggregation type for UUID = Count

You may have to play with `COUNT` vs `COUNT distinct`

If you want tbe count to appear in brackets like this:

```
linked_term (count)
```

On UUID field use **Rewrite results**:

```
({{ uuid }})
```

Note that it is using the new Twig template language notation.

Comment: Thx, works for me with COUNT, additionally I had to set the DB query settings to unique (Drupal 11).

Answer (score 3):

Differently from what stated in the other answer for Drupal 8.0.6, there is a field for the node ID, in Drupal 8.1.3.

With Drupal 8.1.3, I followed these steps:

- I created a view of taxonomy terms, limiting them to the ones of just a vocabulary (in my case *Blog categories*)
- As relationship, I added *Content using field_blog_category*, where *field_blog_category* is the field I added to a content type I created
- I checked *Use aggregration*
- I added *ID* (listed under the *Content* category) as new field
- I set *Aggregration type* to *Count* for the new field (by clicking on *Aggregration settings* for that field)

What I got was the following one (as seen from the preview).

> [image: screenshot]

Following the steps I listed, but using *UUID* as new field (still listed under the *Content* category), I would have obtained the same result.

As expected, also the resulting query didn't change much, using the node ID or its UUID.

#### Using the node ID

```
SELECT taxonomy_term_field_data.name AS taxonomy_term_field_data_name, COUNT(field_blog_category_taxonomy_term_field_data.nid) AS field_blog_category_taxonomy_term_field_data_nid, MIN(taxonomy_term_field_data.tid) AS tid, MIN(field_blog_category_taxonomy_term_field_data.nid) AS field_blog_category_taxonomy_term_field_data_nid_1
FROM 
{taxonomy_term_field_data} taxonomy_term_field_data
LEFT JOIN {node__field_blog_category} node__field_blog_category ON taxonomy_term_field_data.tid = node__field_blog_category.field_blog_category_target_id AND node__field_blog_category.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {node_field_data} field_blog_category_taxonomy_term_field_data ON node__field_blog_category.entity_id = field_blog_category_taxonomy_term_field_data.nid
WHERE (( (taxonomy_term_field_data.vid IN  ('blog_categories')) ))
GROUP BY taxonomy_term_field_data_name
LIMIT 21 OFFSET 0
```

#### Using the node UUID

```
SELECT taxonomy_term_field_data.name AS taxonomy_term_field_data_name, COUNT(field_blog_category_taxonomy_term_field_data__node.uuid) AS field_blog_category_taxonomy_term_field_data__node_uuid, MIN(taxonomy_term_field_data.tid) AS tid, MIN(field_blog_category_taxonomy_term_field_data.nid) AS field_blog_category_taxonomy_term_field_data_nid
FROM 
{taxonomy_term_field_data} taxonomy_term_field_data
LEFT JOIN {node__field_blog_category} node__field_blog_category ON taxonomy_term_field_data.tid = node__field_blog_category.field_blog_category_target_id AND node__field_blog_category.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {node_field_data} field_blog_category_taxonomy_term_field_data ON node__field_blog_category.entity_id = field_blog_category_taxonomy_term_field_data.nid
INNER JOIN {node} field_blog_category_taxonomy_term_field_data__node ON field_blog_category_taxonomy_term_field_data.nid = field_blog_category_taxonomy_term_field_data__node.nid
WHERE (( (taxonomy_term_field_data.vid IN  ('blog_categories')) ))
GROUP BY taxonomy_term_field_data_name
LIMIT 21 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Is there some new way to do this in drupal 8.3.7? Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: You need to edit relationship in advanced setting.

Comment: How can i rewrite the output of this to taxonomy term(count) ?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a Drupal core bug with the taxonomy Content with term relationship.
Patch in https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2674832#comment-10890660
Let me use other content fields to filter (content type, not just UUID) to get a count.