# Similar/related tags block

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

There are a lot of ways to build similar content block according to their tags. Is there any way to build similar tags block?

I try to build similar/related tags block.

I want to look at contents and common tags they have. How many times they added to contents together. Something like this:

[image]

For example: for first column green is similar for blue. For the third column yellow and blue similar for green.

Answer (score 0):

- Create one content views for block
- Relationship > Taxonomy term: Content with term
- aggregation setting yes
- use count on aggregation setting for the field.

There are other options available over [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/views-and-node-count-for-taxonomy-terms).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w22Utjm-chs

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not exactly what I need.. I try to find related tags according to a tag.. I want to show barcelona, real madrid etc. when I go to La Liga tag's page. Because most the times La Liga and barcelona/real madrid adds to content together.. And I want to reach that relativity according to with this count.